# Encoding array byte to string

Tags: c#, xamarin, nfc

I cloned the project from GitHub:https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/CardReader

The project works, but at the output it gives a string in the form "o2�\a�\0\0\0�'PVISA_-ruen�8\f�f��7_*�\f\b�Z`CC" instead of information about a bank card. We tried to change encodings, it does not help. Maybe someone came across this problem and there is a solution?

Comment: Well, I can see "VISA" in there, so: I'd be fine with believing that it has read correctly; what makes you think that the data is meant to be a string? (most chunks of binary: are not strings, in the text sense)

Comment: Please don't hide code behind links. If you have a question about a specific part of that project's code, and its license allows it, please provide a snippet of that code here.

Comment: I suspect its due to Text encoding Try utf encoding

Comment: What's *origin* array (`byte[]`), please?